# Syntax error on token(s), misplaced construct(s) in Ecplise

Tags: java, android

So, this is one of error which I got while I'm building one Android application for our college. I searched for bunch of ideas how to make most of things work and I got it. Now I have issue

Description Resource Path Location Type Syntax error on token(s), misplaced construct(s) on resource at line 41 (code should be down, just part where is problem). I searched for unclosed brackets and I really have no clue what I'm doing wrong for now hour and half (yes, I'm wiriting this at 2am, and yes I'm sleepy now).

So  code is

```
/**
 * moj.tvz.hr Android aplikacija
 * 
 * @author Marko Idžan
 * @version 1.0 beta1
 * 
 */

/**
 * Name of package in Android settings
 */
package mojtvz.webview;

//Importing some libraries which are needed to app work
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;


public class MojTVZWebview extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.webview);
        final WebView pregled = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webview);
        pregled.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        pregled.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {



            @Override
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url)  {
                pregled.loadUrl("javascript:document.getElementsByClassName('footer')[0].style.display = 'none';");

            }

            pregled.loadUrl("https://moj.tvz.hr/prikaz/mojvijes");   



        });


    }
```

Problem is in line

```
pregled.loadUrl("https://moj.tvz.hr/prikaz/mojvijes");
```

If you find any error answer so I can try find what I f*cked up. Thanks

Comment: That line isn't inside a method in the anonymous class.

Comment: Do you have idea how to fix that. Sorry for incovinence but I'm tired and have no idea for more fixings.

Comment: Move that line outside of `new WebViewClient() { ... }` or inside the `onPageFinished` method.